# Should I create classes for each different constructor or should i just create two constructor for one class?

Tags: oop, constructor, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle, open-closed-principle

I am new to oop.so i am just experimenting  some stuffs.The below problem is just a made up problem but it would  help me to understand oop more clearly.

I am coding  to make a calculator which can only add and multiply deciaml number  and binary number.

So I have an abstract  class named Calculator and two child  classes- binaryCalculator  and decimalCalculator

There are two abstract  function  in my Calculator class- add(), multiply()

Now the problem is, only decimal  add() function  does add three numbers  altogether,the rest perform only on  two numbers  .

So now I  am kinda confused,should i make two constructor  in deciamCalculator class or should i just create 4 individual child classes - drciamAddingCalculator, decimalMultiplyingCalculator, binaryAddingCalculator and
binaryMultiplyingCalculator

Comment: Why would the decimal calculator take 3 numbers?

Comment: Anyway, sometimes it's easier to build things seperatly and then see if you can find a common abstraction. Start with `BinaryCalculator` and `DecimalCalculator`, find commonalities and see if you can abstract these in strategies or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also not understanding why the decimal calculator would need 3 numbers, but one possible approach is to have the `add()` and `multiply()` take an arbitrary amount of numbers and add/multiply them all together.

Javacript example:

```
class DecimalCalulator extends AbstractCalculator {
  add(...numbers: number[]): number {
    return numbers.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n);
  }
  multiply(...numbers: number[]): number {
    return numbers.reduce((product, n) => product * n);
  }
}
```

Note that these methods can be `static`, so already we start to question why this is a class an what an instance of this class represents.

If the instance has stored the previous number as a property, then `add()` and `multiply()` should take only **one** number and be `void` methods which modify the stored value.

```
class AbstractCalculator {
  protected total: number = 0;
  /*... */
}

class DecimalCalulator extends AbstractCalculator {
  add(number: number): void {
    this.total += number;
  }
  multiply(number: number): void {
    this.total *= number;
  }
}
```

There are a lot of ways to think about this beyond just classical inheritance.  You don't need to use inheritance at all if you don't want to.

Perhaps one of `BinaryOperations` and `DecimalOperations` is passed into the constructor of a `Calculator` and stored as an instance variable `this.operations`.

Now the single responsibility of the `Calculator` class is to store a rolling total and update it when operations are called.  It can have methods like `clear()` and `undo()`.  It doesn't know about the actual math because it delegates that to `this.operations.add()`. Note that the `Operations` interface is essentially `static` here, so there's room to rethink this further.

```
interface Operations {
  add(...numbers: number[]): number;
  multiply(...numbers: number[]): number;
}

class Calculator {
  private total: number;
  private readonly operations: Operations;

  constructor( operations: Operations ) {
    this.total = 0;
    this.operations = operations;
  }

  clear(): void {
    this.total = 0;
  }

  add( number: number ): void {
    this.total = this.operations.add(this.total, number);
  }

  multiply( number: number ): void {
    this.total = this.operations.multiply(this.total, number);
  }
}
```

If this is an interactive calculator, think about what order the actions are called in.  You're not just calling an add method with a number, right?  You would press the add button first, then enter the number (one digit at a time), and then press the equals button.  No math is done until equals is pressed, and the calculator needs to store knowledge of which number and which operation were pressed.

So in that case instead of passing in an `Operations` object with methods for each operation, perhaps we pass in an array of `Operation` handlers, where an operation has a `key` or a `symbol` (which we use when storing the last button pressed) and a `callback` to call when the time is right.

```
interface ButtonHandler {
  symbol: string;
  callback( previousValue: number, enteredValue: number ): number;
}

const DecimalAdd: ButtonHandler = {
  symbol: '+',
  callback: ( a, b ) => a + b,
} // this is a plain javascript object, not a class, but it implements out interface
```

I could go on, but that should be enough food for thought.